# Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined after upgrade from angular8 to angular9

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9

I am getting errorafter upgrading angular7 application to angular9.

First i have updated to angular8 then doing 9 upgrade.Its compiling but after running the application i am getting the error.

**Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined
    at UIView._applyUpdatedConfig (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@uirouter/angular/lib/directives/uiView.js:269)
    at UIView._viewConfigUpdated (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@uirouter/angular/lib/directives/uiView.js:255)
    at configureUIView (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@uirouter/core/lib-esm/view/view.js:156)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ViewService.sync (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@uirouter/core/lib-esm/view/view.js:164)
    at ViewService.registerUIView (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@uirouter/core/lib-esm/view/view.js:191)
    at UIView.ngOnInit (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@uirouter/angular/lib/directives/uiView.js:131)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:22505)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:31069)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:31031)
```

Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'login-component',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.less'],
    animations: [
        trigger('slideInAnimation', [
            transition(':enter', [
                style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }),
                animate(
                    '1s ease-in-out',
                    style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' })
                )
            ]),
            transition(':leave', [
                style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }),
                animate(
                    '1s ease-in-out',
                    style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' })
                )
            ])
        ])
    ]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    
    @ViewChild('uname', { static: true }) uname: any;

    constructor(
        private loginService: LoginService,
        private store: Store<AppState>,
        private titleService: Title        
    ) {
       
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        if (this.uname !== undefined) {
            this.uname.nativeElement.focus();
        }
    }
        
}
```

Comment: What does your component look like?

Comment: updated in issue

Comment: This was working before upgrading?

Comment: yes when i ugrade to 8 it was working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this was working before, it seems as if the issue is simply coming from the NodeModules.

First, delete the folder: `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` from your app. You can do this in the folder on your computer, or within your text editor. Note, it might take a few minutes to delete. This is normal.

After this is deleted, close and restart your app in your text editor. Then, in your terminal, type `npm install`. This will also take a few minutes, but when complete you will notice your `node_modules` folder has returned.

Try running the app from here using `ng serve` or `npm start`.

If the issue persists, let me know. There may be a missing step from when you updated your Angular.

Comment: did you follow these steps? https://update.angular.io/#7.0:9.0

Comment: its working now i have missed in updating to 8.2 , once i have done i will be able to update to angular 9.1. To compile an run the aplication i have set  "enableIvy": false then only it is working. But i need to set enableIvy:true any sugession

Answer (score 0):

I have a non-cli hybrid application so my upgrades were manual. I faced the same issue (Angular 8 to 9) but reinstalling my node modules didn't help me. I ended up starting off with the upgrade process again. Again, I found myself facing errors with @ui-router module. And these helped me with fixing them:

1. Move to @ui-router/angular-hybrid@10.0.0 - https://github.com/ui-router/angular-hybrid/issues/374
2. Include @ui-router/core in your project or install the peer-dependencies manually - https://github.com/ui-router/angular-hybrid/releases/tag/10.0.0
3. Ensure there are no multiple copies of @ui-router modules - https://githubmemory.com/repo/ui-router/core/issues/671